# JQuery filter(string selector) does not work in combination with find()

Tags: jquery, filter, find, selector

### Starting Situation

These two commands should be equivalent.

```
jQuery('a').filter(':contains(about)');
```

and

```
jQuery.find('a').filter(':contains(about)');
```

### Problem

In fact, the first command performs well, whereas the second throws the following exception:

```
TypeError: :contains(about) is not a function
```

Why ist that? Shouldn't `jQuery('a')` and `jQuery.find('a')` return the same object? If not, what's the difference?

### Explanation

I am dynamically building a JQuery command chain (part of a JQuery Java Wrapper which is used in my project [Abmash](https://github.com/alp82/abmash)). Therefore, i prefer a chain of methods like `jQuery.find('a').filter(':contains(about)')`.

Comment: Don't use `jQuery.find`. It isn't part of the officially supported API. They could make it disappear in some future release. You should be doing something more like `jQuery(document).find('a').filter(...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery.find('a')` returns a array (`Array.filter()` takes a function as argument.)

`jQuery('a')` returns a jQuery-array-like-Object

Comment: That explains it. Is there a method which can be used as equivalent for `jQuery('a')`? For example something like `jQuery.select('a')`?

Comment: *"...returns a array"* That's not correct. They both return the same type of jQuery object.

Comment: @Alp why would you need that? It sounds like this is a small part of a bigger problem? If you need to parameterise your selector you can do this: `var selector = 'a'; jQuery(selector).filter(...);`

Comment: @amnotiam I tested in `firebug console`. `$.isArray($.find('a'))` yields `true`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are right, i explained it in my edited question.

Comment: @kev: Sorry, you're right. I didn't notice that OP was calling `.find` directly on the jQuery function instead of from a jQuery object. `jQuery.find` is not part of the official API, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: The $.find() indeed returns an array and not a jQuery wrapped set. The $('selector').find() however does return a wrapped set. I did not know this and could not find any documentation online. Learned something new today. :)

Comment: Thanks to all, and @koenp please consider upvoting my question if you learned something :)

Comment: @Alp Should have thought of that myself. Done. :)

Answer (score 1):

A static call to find ($.find()) returns an array and not a wrapped set. What you're looking for is this I think:

```
$('a:contains(about)');
```

Comment: You can try the code i provided above on this page with Firebug. It should be reproducable. Also, i added an "Explanation" section in my question to clarify why i need this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not know that a static call of find ($.find()) returns a plain array instead of a wrapped set (jQuery array), but I guess it does. I does not show up in the jQuery docs and I think you'd better not use it this way as it might get broken in future versions.